# Xampp mysql memory engine temporary table full error 1114

Tags: mysql, memory, xampp, temp-tables

Hello I have a problem caused by a full table error. This is how I create the table inside a stored procedure I run:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_text (
    id INT DEFAULT 0,
    string varchar(400) DEFAULT ''
) engine = memory;
```

I then try to pull about 55000 records into the table, which does not seem like too many however the table is giving me a `table full` error. There is some guidance on how to use `tmp_table_size=32M` and `max_heap_table_size=32M` to fix this in my.cnf, but I cannot find these terms anywhere my xampp installation. Does anyone know where these terms are kept on an xampp installation?

And also more importantly, is there a way to change the values of `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` for only the execution of my stored procedure? That would be ideal. Is there anything like `ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');` which is how I would solve this if this were a PHP script. Thank you to anyone that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe xampp/etc/my.cnf? If it's not there you can simply add this rows and check it by [SHOW VARIABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html) statement.